# Assertion Error on Android 5 while executing ksoap2 operation

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am getting the error message bellow while executing web service operation with ksoap2. This problem only occurs in Android 5.

```
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2243
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786): Process: com.univera.android, PID: 9786
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786): java.lang.AssertionError
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:532)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient.copyWithDefaults(OkHttpClient.java:494)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient.open(OkHttpClient.java:467)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient.open(OkHttpClient.java:462)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler.openConnection(HttpHandler.java:33)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:479)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.<init>(ServiceConnectionSE.java:51)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.getServiceConnection(HttpTransportSE.java:188)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:119)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:90)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at com.univera.core.ws.WebServiceCall.call(WebServiceCall.java:66)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at com.univera.business.ws.WSICall.SendUmpSQLite(WSICall.java:236)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at com.univera.util.TransferBusinessManager.arsivlenenBilgiGonder(TransferBusinessManager.java:333)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at com.univera.util.TransferBusinessManager.bilgiArsivleGonder(TransferBusinessManager.java:243)
10-06 11:01:45.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9786):     at com.univera.util.TransferBusinessManager$SQLiteDBSenderThread.run(TransferBusinessManager.java:546)
```

I found the same problem mentioned in [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/4KSyRF83hI0) but it didn't get any response.

Comment: Just remove .idea files from project. And import project again may work for you

Comment: @Sree I am getting this error on Eclipse

Comment: do you updated jdk?>